# WPF XAML resize <infrastructure:Plugin> width to the content in it

Tags: c#, xaml, resize, wpf-controls

I have an interface with some tabs in it on the right side of the screen. I need each tab`s width to be resized by width of the context in it.
*All the other tabs do it apart from this one...*
Any suggestions, please?

> **Description**
>
> The scales tab in the stackup editor doesn’t resize when selected.
>
> Select the scales tab on the right side of the stackup editor
>
> Right hand tab doesn’t resize
>
> **Expected Behaviour**
>
> Tab resizes to fit content, as with all other tabs in the stackup
> editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU9ro.png)

```
<infrastructure:Plugin x:Class="Xact.GeminiX.Plugin.PanelEditors.Views.DisplayScalesView"
                           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                           xmlns:infrastructure="clr-namespace:Xact.GeminiX.Client.Common.Infrastructure;assembly=Xact.GeminiX.Client.Common"
                           xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Xact.GeminiX.Client.Wpf.Common.Converters;assembly=Xact.GeminiX.Client.Wpf.Common"
                           xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                           xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
                           LayoutUpdated="ViewLayoutUpdated"
                           Loaded="Plugin_Loaded">
        <infrastructure:Plugin.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityHiddenOnFalseConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityHiddenOnFalseConverter"></converters:BooleanToVisibilityHiddenOnFalseConverter>
            <infrastructure:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy"/>
        </infrastructure:Plugin.Resources>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <infrastructure:DataContextProxyBehavior DataContextProxy="{StaticResource DataContextProxy}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        
        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ImportContextMenu"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ScalingImportExportMetaData.ScalingImportFormats, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}">
    
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    
                            <Setter Property="Header" 
                                    Value="{Binding FormatTitle}"/>
    
                            <Setter Property="Command"
                                    Value="{Binding DataContext.FormatSelectionCommand, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"/>
    
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" 
                                    Value="{Binding}"/>
    
                        </Style>
    
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    
                </ContextMenu>
    
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ImportFromStackupContextMenu">
    
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding StoredLocalisation}" Click="ButtonImportFromStackupStored_OnClick"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding RemakesLocalisation}" Click="ButtonImportFromStackupRemakes_OnClick"/>
    
                </ContextMenu>
    
                <ContextMenu  x:Key="ContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ScalingImportExportMetaData.ScalingExportFormats, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    
                            <Setter Property="Header" 
                                    Value="{Binding FormatTitle}"/>
    
                            <EventSetter Event="Click"
                                    Handler="MenuItem_OnClick"/>
    
                        </Style>
    
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ContextMenu>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ExportButtonTemplate">
                    <telerik:RadButton Content="{Binding TypeTitle}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" Margin="2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                          Grid.Column="0">
    
                <Grid>
    
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <converters:BooleanInvertConverter x:Key="BooleanInvertConverter"></converters:BooleanInvertConverter>
                </Grid.Resources>
    
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Loaded="TopGrid_OnLoaded" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Grid">
    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LayerLocalisation}" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding FirstScaleFactorLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding SecondScaleFactorLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
    
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ArtworkLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PredictedLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ArtworkLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding PredictedLocalisation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
    
                    <Border Grid.Row="2" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
                            BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0" 
                            Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" 
                            BorderBrush="LightGray" />
    
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Text="{Binding AllLocalisation}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Margin="5" />
    
                    <TextBox x:Name="EnabledTemplate" 
                             Grid.Row="3" 
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Margin="5" 
                             Text="{Binding ShortValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             KeyDown="SetShortValues_OnKeyDown"
                             TextChanged="ShortValueTextbox_TextChanged"
                             Width="80" 
                             IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                             MaxLength="10" />
    
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="3" 
                                       Grid.Column="2" 
                                       Content="{Binding SetFirstLocalisation}" 
                                       Click="SetShortButton_OnClick" 
                                       IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                                       Margin="2"/>
    
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" 
                             Grid.Column="3" 
                             Margin="5" 
                             Text="{Binding LongValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             KeyDown="SetLongValues_OnKeyDown"
                             TextChanged="ShortValueTextbox_TextChanged"
                             Width="80" 
                             IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                             MaxLength="10" />
    
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="3" 
                                       Grid.Column="4" 
                                       Content="{Binding SetSecondLocalisation}" 
                                       Click="SetLongButton_OnClick" 
                                       IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                                       Margin="2"/>
    
                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="4" 
                              Grid.Column="0" 
                              IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding AllCheckboxIsChecked}"
                              Margin="5"
                              Click="SetAllCheckBoxToggled" />
    
                        <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="4"
                                           Grid.Column="2" 
                                           Content="{Binding PredictedSwapLocalisation}" 
                                           Click="PredictedShortButton_OnClick" 
                                           IsEnabled="{Binding PredictionsAvailable}"
                                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PredictedShortButtonID"
                                           x:Name="PredictedShortButtonID"
                                           Margin="2"/>
    
                        <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="4" 
                                           Grid.Column="4" 
                                           Content="{Binding PredictedSwapLocalisation}" 
                                           Click="PredictedLongButton_OnClick" 
                                           IsEnabled="{Binding PredictionsAvailable}"
                                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PredictedLongButtonID"
                                           x:Name="PredictedLongButtonID"
                                           Margin="2"/>
    
                    <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10" BorderBrush="LightGray" />
    
                </Grid>
    
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="ScrollViewer" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
                        <Grid>
    
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="RowsTemplate">
    
                                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateGrid">
    
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
    
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}" 
                                                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CheckBoxChangedCommand, ElementName=Grid}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Layer}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
    
                                        </Grid>
    
                                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                                                 Text="{Binding ShortDisplayValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}" 
                                                 Width="80" 
                                                 Margin="5" 
                                                 TextChanged="ShortValueTextbox_TextChanged"
                                                 KeyDown="FirstUIElement_OnKeyDown" 
                                                 LostFocus="FirstUIElement_OnLostFocus" />
    
                                        <telerik:RadButton Grid.Column="2" 
                                                           Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetSinglePredictedShortCommand, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                           IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}" 
                                                           Visibility="{Binding Visible}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                                           Margin="2">
                                            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                        <Label Background="{Binding ConfidenceBrush}" Foreground="{Binding ConfidenceForegroundBrush}" Height="20" Width="20" Content="{Binding ConfidenceCharacter}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0"></Label>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortButton}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
                                        </telerik:RadButton>
    
                                        <TextBox Grid.Column="3"
                                                 Text="{Binding LongDisplayValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}"
                                                 Width="80"
                                                 Margin="5"
                                                 TextChanged="ShortValueTextbox_TextChanged"
                                                 KeyDown="SecondUIElement_OnKeyDown" 
                                                 LostFocus="SecondUIElement_OnLostFocus" />
    
                                        <telerik:RadButton Grid.Column="4"
                                                           Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetSinglePredictedLongCommand, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                           IsEnabled="{Binding Editable}"
                                                           Visibility="{Binding Visible}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                                           Margin="2">
                                            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                        <Label Background="{Binding ConfidenceBrush}" Foreground="{Binding ConfidenceForegroundBrush}" Height="20" Width="20" Content="{Binding ConfidenceCharacter}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0"></Label>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LongButton}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
                                        </telerik:RadButton>
    
                                    </Grid>
    
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
    
                            <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RowsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" />
    
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
    
                <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" BorderBrush="LightGray" />
    
                <Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                               Content="{Binding SwapAllLocalisation}"
                               Click="SwapAllButton_OnClick"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                               Content="{Binding SetAllPredictedLocalisation}" 
                               Click="SetAllPredictedButton_OnClick" 
                               IsEnabled="{Binding PredictionsAvailable}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                               Content="{Binding ResetLocalisation}" 
                               Click="ResetButton_OnClick" 
                               IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" 
                               Content="{Binding ArtworkRevisionsLocalisation}" 
                               Click="ArtworkRevisionsButton_OnClick"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding ArtworksButtonEnabled}"
                               Visibility="{Binding ArtworksButtonVisible, Converter={ StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityHiddenOnFalseConverter}}"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0" 
                               Content="{Binding ImportLocalisation}"  
                               Click="ButtonImport_Click"  
                               IsEnabled="{Binding ScalesExist}" 
                               ContextMenu="{StaticResource ImportContextMenu}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="2"/>
                    <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" 
                               Content="{Binding StackupImportLocalisation}"  
                               Click="ButtonImportFromStackup_OnClick" 
                               ContextMenu="{StaticResource ImportFromStackupContextMenu}"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding CanImportFromStackup}"
                               Visibility="{Binding ImportFromStackupEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="2"/>
    
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column ="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ScalingImportExportMetaData.ScalingExportTypes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExportButtonTemplate}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
    
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SingleCoresLocalisation}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding UseSingleCores}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
    
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndividualCopperLocalisation}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding UseSingleCores, Converter={ StaticResource BooleanInvertConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
             </Grid>
    
        </ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <converters:NonZeroDoubleToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NonZeroDoubleToVisibilityConverter" />
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="D"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10"
                           ViewportSize="{Binding ViewportHeight, ElementName=ScrollViewer}"
                           Maximum="{Binding ScrollableHeight, ElementName=ScrollViewer}"
                           Scroll="ScrollBar_OnScroll" Name="ScrollBar"
                           Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Maximum, Converter={StaticResource NonZeroDoubleToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    
            </Grid>
    
        </Grid>
    </infrastructure:Plugin>
```